# Double quote in the name of table in select query of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am running following simple select query in PostgreSQL:

`SELECT * FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE"`

It gives me following error report:

```
ERROR:  relation "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE"
                      ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 15
```

But when I am running the following query it runs successfully:

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`

Again when I select from a table created by me the situation is reversed. Following one fails:

`SELECT * FROM countryTable`

while following one runs successfully.

`SELECT * FROM "countryTable"`

Why is it happening? What is the problem?

Comment: Double quoted identifiers are case sensitive, non-quoted identifiers are folded to lower case (the standard says that they should be folded to upper case though). You can `\d tablename` from `psql` to see what the columns, tables, ... are really called.

Answer (score 4):

You probably created your table so:

```
CREATE TABLE "countryTable" (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  country TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Which create a tablespace wrapped in `""`, you shouldn't use double quote in general in postgres for table names or columns, try without double quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE countryTable (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  country TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

An then you can use this query you already have `SELECT * FROM countryTable`

Comment: Suppose I am querying in a database created by others. Then how would I know if I have to add double quote or not?

Comment: I would probably talk with them if they are a company providing a service and highlight that this is bad practice, and in fact you are now in a position where you don't know if you should use double quotes or not and the only way is trying and guessing, which is probably not what this company had in mind. If it's something you have access on or internal to your company I would make a backup of the database and change the table names to a standard format, then drop the old table and upload the new one. Short answer there's no way of knowing if you don't try every table as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

While my personal advice is to use legal, lower-case names exclusively and never use double-quote, it is no problem per se.

When you look at the table definition in psql (`\d tbl`), or at table names in the [system catalog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalogs.html) `pg_class` or column names in `pg_attributes` or any of the [information schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/information-schema.html) views, you get identifiers in their correct spelling (and with all other oddities that may have been preserved by double-quoting them). You can use `quote_ident()` to quote such names automatically as needed - it only adds double quotes if necessary.

Postgres itself isn't foolish enough to use CaMeL case names. All objects in the information schema or in the system catalog are lower-cased (the names of the system tables and columns, *not* the names of user tables they carry as data).

Start at the basics, read the [manual about identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).